# Is there an optimal algorithm to calculate $2^n - 1$ in $\theta(n^n)$

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

The sequence $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is defined by $f_{0} := 0, f_{1} := 1$ and $f_{n} := 3f_{n-1}-2f_{n-2}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}_{0} \setminus \{0,1\}$.

**Is there an algorithm that takes an $n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ and returns $f_{n}$ in $\theta(n^n)$ ?**

The algorithm needs to be efficient (means there must not be any loops or calculations for artificially slow down the algorithm).

Two very short (just descriptive) examples for the calculation in $\theta(1)$ and $\theta(2^n)$:

$\theta(1)$: set the $n_{th}$ bit to 1 and subtract 1

$\theta(2^n)$: the recursive form $f_{n} := 3f_{n-1}-2f_{n-2}$

Comment: Hint : consider the polynomial $x^2-3x+2$, what obvious geometric series can you find that validate the recursive equation $f_n-3f_{n}+2f_{n-2}=0$ ?

Comment: Can you name the obvious geometric series? taylor?

Comment: As I reread your question, something puzzles me : if computing $3f_{n-1}-2f_{n-2}$ takes $\theta(2^n)$, then doesn't computing $f_n$ from $f_0$ takes $\theta(n 2^n)$ ? And this is asymptotically dominated by $\theta(n^n)$, so straightforward recursive computation takes less than $\theta(n^n)$.

Comment: Sorry, that might have been a missunderstanding: The number of recursive calculations from $f_{0}$ to $f_{n}$ takes $\theta(n2^n)$. Just calling $3f_{n-1} - 2f_{n-2}$ does not cost very much. Especially not $\theta(2^n)$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following, . Does recursively computing $f_n$ from $f_0$ takes $\theta(n2^n)$ ? How much cost computing $3f_{n-1}-2f_{n-2}$ once ? Please clafirify because your sentences seems to contradict each other.

Comment: SORRY! Mistake! :D The recursive calculations from $f_{0}$ to $f_{n}$ take altogether $\theta(2^n)$.

Depending on the number of digits in $n$ and the architecture of the computer, a single calculation of $3f_{n-1} - 2f_{n-2}$ might just take $\theta(1)$ (e.g. the n will never exceed $2^{32}$ on a 32 bit machine).